# Replacing ManagedExecutorService with ExecutorService in test

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, mockito, wildfly

I have some service which uses an Java EE [`ManagedExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) (in Wildfly 9)

```
public class FooService{
    @Resource
    ManagedExecutorService executorService;
}
```

For a test with Mockito, I would like to use a "normal" [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooServiceTest{
   @Spy
   ManagedExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}
```

This code obviously does not compile, as an `ExecutorService` is not a `ManagedExecutorService`.

When using an `ExecutorService` in the service, the test runs without errors, but then Wildfly cannot inject the service.

```
public class FooService{
    @Resource
    ExecutorService executorService;
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FooServiceTest {
   @Spy
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}
```

It would be possible to create a `ManagedExecutorService` by delegating to a `ExecutorService`:

```
@Spy
ManagedExecutorService executorService = new ManagedExecutorService() {

   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
   @Override
   public void shutdown() {
       executorService.shutdown();
   }

   // delegate for all (12) methods
}
```

**Is there a simpler way to use an `ExecutorService` in the test without changing the service which runs in Wildfly?**

Comment: Why do you need a non-mock instance of `ManagedExecutorService`? That's an interface which can easily be mocked.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: Well it is not a unit test, so the tasks submitted to the ExecutorService should actually run. It would be possible to use Arquillian, but I thought it may be simpler to just use an Java SE ExecutorService.

Comment: Then why not use a mock that runs the submitted tasks? Just implement Answer accordingly http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html

Comment: @SpaceTrucker: Well for simple Runnables this is possible but if the service uses the Future returned by saying submit, it gets complicated, does it not?

Comment: I think you need to rethink the scope of the test. If the scope is to actually run the tasks within the environment provided by a `ManagedExecutorService` than you actually need to provide it and make this test using a cleanly started container.

Answer (score 0):

I use injection pattern:

```
class DefaultImpl {
 static DefaultFactory me;
 static DefaultFactory getCurrentInstance()
  { if (me == null) {
     me = new DefaultFactory();
    }
    return me;
  }
void setCurrentInstance(DefaultFactory df){
  me = df;
}
 ExecutorService getExecutorService(){
   // lookup and return ManagedExecutorService
 }
}
class TestImpl extends DefaultImpl{
  TestImpl(){
    DefaultFactory.setCurrentInstance(this); <-- this now sets your TestImpl for any call
  }
  ExecutorService getExecutorService(){
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    return executorService;
  }
}

//junit
@Test
void someTest(){
 new TestImpl();
 // do something all your calls will use non managed executor service
}
```

You can also call new TestImpl() from junit setup(). Also if you want to make it more flexible then you can have a BaseImpl and have both DefaultImpl and TestImpl extend it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching for an answer: I mocked the `ManagedExecutorService` and used `CompletableFuture.runAsync(...)` in combination with an `ExecutorService` to implement the mocked behavior:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class SomeServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
    @Mock
    private ServiceCalledAsyncly serviceCalledAsyncly;

    private SomeService someService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        var testExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        when(managedExecutorService.runAsync(any())).then(invocation -> {
            Runnable runnable = invocation.getArgument(0);
            return CompletableFuture.runAsync(runnable, testExecutorService);
        });

        doAnswer((invocation) -> {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return null;
        }).when(serviceCalledAsyncly).doSomethingLongRunning();

        someService = new SomeService(managedExecutorService, serviceCalledAsyncly);
    }

    // your tests...
}
```